# "call to undefined function" error when calling class method

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

this is the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function assign(`
this is the code, as you can see i obviously have defined the function so why is it not working

```
class shades {
    function create($name, $shades, $slug, $shortDesc, $longDesc, $position){
        $name = sanitize_paranoid_string($name);
        $slug = slug($name);
        $shortDesc = sanitize_sql_string($shortDesc);
        $longDesc = sanitize_sql_string($longDesc);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (type, name, slug, shortDesc, htmlDesc, position)VALUES('shades','$name','$slug','$shortDesc','$longDesc','$position')")or die(mysql_error());  
        $ID = mysql_insert_id();
        assign($shades, $ID);
        if($query) {return true;}
        else {return false;};
    }
    function delassign($toID){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM assign WHERE type='shades' AND toID='$toID'")or die(mysql_error());    
    }
    function assign($shades, $toID)
    {
        foreach($shades as $shade)
        {
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO assign(type, typeID, toID)VALUES('shades','$shade','$toID')")or die(mysql_error());
            if($result){echo "Added!";}
            else{echo"Not Added!";}
        };  
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample code might be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) in function `delassign`. To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql driver to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements). Note this is superior to explicit sanitization because while you can forget to sanitize, there is nothing security-wise to forget with prepared statement parameters (if you forget a parameter, PHP will generate an error informing you).

Comment: ... If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You dont have a function named `assign()`, but a method with this name. PHP is not Java and in PHP you have to make clear, if you want to call a function

```
assign()
```

or a method

```
$object->assign()
```

In your case the call to the function resides inside another method. `$this` always refers to the object, in which a method exists, itself.

```
$this->assign()
```

Comment: so, a PHP class method whose definition starts with the keyword `function` is not actually a function? The fact that you need to use `$this->` to call it seems inconsistent (IMHO) with not having to pre-define return types (or even if there is an explicit return value).

Comment: The keyword "function" in PHP is used functions, methods and procedures (update: "and closures"). It _may_ be a real function, that depends on the context. I don't understand where the relation between `$this->` and return types should be. Return types are quite new (at least compared to this answer ;)) and PHP is still under the hood weakly typed. Type declarations are not required.

Answer (score 17):

you need to call the function like this

```
$this->assign()
```

instead of just `assign()`

Answer (score 4):

Mates,

I stumbled upon this error today while testing a simple script.  I am not using "class" function though so it take it with grain of salt.
I was calling function before its definition & declaration ...something like this

```
      try{
             foo();
         }
       catch (exception $e)
           {
            echo "$e->getMessage()";
           }

       function foo(){
                       echo "blah blah blah";
                     }
```

so php was throwing me error "call to undefined function ".

This kinda seem classic programming error but may help someone in need of clue.

Answer (score 0):

Another silly mistake you can do is copy recursive function from non class environment to class and don`t change inner self calls to $this->method_name()

i`m writing this because couldn`t understand why i got this error and this thread is first in google when you search for this error.

Comment: "i`m writing this because couldn`t understand why i got this error and this thread is first in google " That's really smart. Thanks.